# aligning content

Tags: formatting, cv, alignment, resume

I'm new to LaTeX and I am facing a small problem...

Is there a way to define, that it automatically aligns to the farthest second column object?
**or in other words:**
The second column should automatically align to a defined space (orange arrow) between the longest object in column one.

[image: Screenshot]

Here a link to the source code: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rgskjktntgdf

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tabular environment does this. In altacv, it can be used like this:

```
\personalinfo{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \phone{+xx xxx xx xx}
        & \mailaddress{Example Street 168, 9999 Town} \\

      \email{andreas.xyzxyzxy@gmail.com}
        & \location{XYZ, Switzerland} \\

      \linkedin{linkedin.com/in/xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz}
        & \birthdate{Born dd.mm.yyyy in XYZ, Switzerland}
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Just make sure that the text is not too wide, so that it doesn't interfere with the picture.

Answer (score 1):

simply use tabbing

the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx length can be varied to suit the interword distance

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
     \newcommand{\signature}{\begin{tabbing}\\


 xxxx\=x\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \kill\\
 \>xxx A        \>      \>Street No \\
  \>andreas      \>     \>Switzerland

    \end{tabbing}}
\signature
\end{document}
```